# "[:too many arguments" error in BASH

Tags: bash, parameters

I'm learning BASH through HackerRank.There's an exercise in which the lengths of the triangle is given and then you need to find whether the triangle is isosceles,scalene or equilateral.I wrote the following code:

```
read a
read b
read c
if  [ [ "$a" -eq  "$b" ] && [ "$b" -eq  "$c" ] ]  
then 
    echo "EQUILATERAL"
    elif  [ [ "$a" -eq "$b" ] || [ "$b" -eq  "$c" ] ]  
    then
    echo "ISOSCELES"
    else
    echo "SCALENE"
    fi
```

But then I get the following error

```
solution.sh: line 4: [: too many arguments
solution.sh: line 7: [: too many arguments
solution.sh: line 7: [: too many arguments
```

Why is this happening? I tried long and hard to rectify it but nothing worked out

Comment: Hmm, I'm not sure how that works. I tried running it through the Terminal but it doesn't work - it gives me the same error as you get, but it also always outputs `SCALENE`.

Comment: try using `-a` and `-o` instead of `&&` and `||`. theese are just usable outside of conditions surrounded with `[...]`. addditionally there could be some problems with `[...]` in a condition. perhaps use paranthesis `(...)` for encapsulating sub conditions.

Comment: I added -a and -o and instead of 3,2 errors showed up.But they were the same errors.

Comment: Hint - `[` is a command, not a grouping operator.

Comment: you've also got a logic bug: hint 2,1,2 is isosceles.

Comment: Came here with this problem, but my solution was here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/162616/why-am-i-getting-too-many-arguments

Answer (score 2):

You can combine conditions either ommiting the surrounding brackets like this

```
if [ "$a" -eq  "$b" ] && [ "$b" -eq  "$c" ]
```

or by combining the conditions with -a/-o like this

```
if [ "$a" -eq  "$b" -a "$b" -eq  "$c" ]
```

see http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/commands/classictest#and_and_or

Answer (score 0):

`&&` and `||` are Bash list operators. In a chain of commands, the next command is executed only if the previous command returned 0 (`&&`) or nonzero (`||`).

`[` is an alias for the Bash internal `test` command and has arguments such as `-eq` or `-ne`. `]` ends its command line. Type `help test` for more information.

So if you write a conditional expression, you do not put the list operators inside brackets.

Try, for example, this instead of the respective line in your code:

```
if  [ "$a" -eq  "$b" ] && [ "$b" -eq  "$c" ]
then
```

Answer (score 0):

`[` isn't a grouping operator in bash, you can't use it to group tests.

there are a number of different ways to express the tests you want to make, numeric evaluation mode is probably easiest to read

```
 if (( a == b && b == c ))

 if (( a == b || b == c || c == a ))
```

This is going to break if you have decimal fractions, but will work fine for integers.

Answer (score -1):

`[` is a conditional command, like an alias for `sh`'s `test` built-in command.

`[[` is the same for `bash` which has more test options.

So make a choice between `[` and `[[` but not `[ [` which means two command.

Example:

```
# [ [ -n 'test' ] ]
bash: [: too many arguments
# [ -n 'test' ] && echo $?
0
# [[ -n 'test' ]] && echo $?
0
```

Comment: Not my down vote, but if `[` is a command, `[ [` is also a command. Just a single command with invalid parameters.